# Let A⊆(0,1) set of real numbers with decimal expansion containing only 0s, 2s, and 4s. Like, 2/9=0.222…∈A, 0.2400424…∈A. Prove that A is uncountable.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

How can I approach this question. First of all these concepts of discrete mathematics are new for me. And what I think is that first I have to say that the numbers are countable and then I will prove that our assumption is wrong. But how can I do this? Probably it may include something like base 3 (0,1,2). *You know what I mean*
And a humble request to all of you that if you can provide me any YouTube link or website link for help then you can. But if you gonna explain this to me (which will be much better) then please try to explain deeply like I haven't enough knowledge about this concept. And feel free to explain any other example if you think I gonna cheat or something like that.

Comment: Your base $3$ idea is good.  Every decimal in $[0,1]$ can be written in base $3$.  That is to say, using exactly $3$ characters.

Comment: I know but I just know that I can use something like base 3,but how can I show the statement by using this?

Comment: If you have a real decimal in base $3$, say $x=.0122102201\cdots$ you can map it to your set by sending $0$ to $0$, $2$ to $2$ and $1$ to $4$, and conversely. Thus $x$ would map to $.0422402204\cdots$.  In that way, we establish a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that the set of infinite binary bit strings is uncountable? Can you find a subset of $A$ with which you can make a bijection with the set of infinite binary bit strings?.  If you prove a subset of $A$ is uncountable, you know all of $A$ is.  Working with base $3$ expansions of the reals would also be fine, but introduces the problem that some reals have two different base $3$ expansions.  That can be fixed, but is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Makes sense. But do we have proof that base 3 is uncountable?

Comment: Yes.  You can just look at the base $3$ expansions that have only $0$ and $1$.  That avoids the dual representation problem and is still uncountable.  Alternately, you can find a bijection between the base $3$ digit strings and the reals.  You only have to swallow countably many points so it isn't hard.  Find a countably infinite sequence of reals, say $2^n$.  Space them out to odd $n$, leaving the even $n$ to absorb one version each of the countably many terminating decimals.

Comment: The bottom line is that if you have a set with infinitely many choices to make to choose an element, it is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cantors diagonal argument.

Let $K$ be a countable list of such decimals.  List them as $\{k_1,k_2, k_3,......\}$.

Let $D_i = $ then $i$th decimal of $k_i$.  But let $E_i = \begin{cases}0& D_i = 2\\ 2&D_i = 4\\ 4& D_i=0\end{cases}$

Let $m = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E_i\cdot \frac 1{10^k}$.    The decimal digits of $m$ contain only $2,0,4$ but $m\not \in K$ so $K$ does not contain all such decimals and no countable set does.